# Xamarin.ios too many files open

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, mvvmcross

We are developing an app with Xamarin and Mvvmcross.

Simply put, our app makes pictures, bundles them together into a zip and sends to our server. (about 15 pictures + some info files)

It works great until point where we get System.IOException: Too Many Files Open.

This indicates that we have a lot of files open, but with no luck we could not find reason why there are any open files.

We are using mostly stock Xamarin and Mvvmcross plugins.

To save/open/read files we use IMvxFileStore plugin, but even when we used .Net System.IO.File it does the same (throw exception).

Some code:

```
public virtual Task<bool> SavePhoto(string name, string photoData, bool saveToLibrary = false)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {

            try
            {
                var photoPath = GetLocalPath("PHOTOS"+ "/");

                if (!_fileStore.FolderExists(photoPath))
                    _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(photoPath);

                var filename = name;
                var filePath = GetLocalPath(filename);

                _fileStore.WriteFile(filePath, photoData);

                if (saveToLibrary)
                {
                    SavePhotoToLibrary(filePath);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

                return false;
            }

        });

    }
```

Sometimes its 40 photos, sometimes 2... Funny that rerunning app again does not help much.
Issue is present in debug/release, and even different devices.

We were helpless to find any topic that helped with this issue.

Is there any way to peek what files are open and where?
Does the app handle opening files or does the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ran into a problem with the same error and I had to increase the ulimit. 
It is possibly not the solution I think but maybe it helps. By default it is around 260 for OSx but I think mono decreases it a bit more. In mono it's called rlimit. There is a e-book with some explanations: 
https://books.google.nl/books?id=FKRL5AOgiC0C&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=increase+ulimit+ios&source=bl&ots=Ti04k9RdWU&sig=XflYmYDD6UNgWka7VPkp3ZY_AWw&hl=nl&sa=X#v=onepage&q=increase%20ulimit%20ios&f=false

**Note on debugging**:
I discovered that we were making too much requests to our api at once, probably it bloated the cache and orphaned some tasks. FileCounter helps in determining which views generate leaks.

Comment: Its 256, got a code which counts used file descriptors, and it seems we have problems with navigation, as after moving from one view to another, file count increases by 10 or more, we have o lot of navigation so, after few minutes it's easily around 256.
https://github.com/sanandrea/FileCounter.Xamarin

Comment: Maybe dispose filestreams that are not used anymore? Maybe you already did that, so I am working still on a better solution.

Comment: Also maybe turn on SGen generational garbage collector in properties - ios build - advanced

Comment: I discovered that we were making too much requests to our api at once, probably it bloated the cache and orphaned some tasks.

FileCounter helps in determining which views generate leaks.